# IntegerDigits[] gave an error despite working properly

Tags: warning-messages

I was running the following code,

```
f[x_] = Total@Select[IntegerDigits[x], OddQ] - 
   Total@Select[IntegerDigits[x], EvenQ];
Select[Range[10000], 
 PrimeQ[11 # - 1] && PrimeQ[11 # + 1] && f[11 #] == 0 &]
```

The error message was

```
IntegerDigits::argb: 调用 IntegerDigits 时使用了 0 个参数；应该用 1 到 3 个参数.
```

which approximately means `IntegerDigits[]` received zero arguments while it requires one to three, in English.

However the output was correct. What is the problem?

Comment: You don't want `f` to evaluate unless its argument is a number. Change its definition to `Clear[f]; f[x_?NumericQ] := Total@Select[IntegerDigits[x], OddQ] - Total@Select[IntegerDigits[x], EvenQ];` Even just using `SetDelayed` instead of `Set` wii get rid of the error message.

Comment: @BobHanlon I see. But why would my code evaluate a non-number into `f`?

Comment: Because the definition of `f` used `Set` and evaluated when defined and there was no value for `x`

Comment: The error comes from the definition code, not from the `Select[Range...]` code. The `Select[Range...]` code should have been omitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your output was correct, it was only accidentally so. Let's walk through this slowly, and let's use a simpler function for clarity.

```
f[x_] = Select[IntegerDigits[x], OddQ]
```

When you evaluate that, you get your error message. But let's first check the result--what did the definition of `f` turn out to be:

```
Information[f]
```

You should see something like this:

```
f[x_] = IntegerDigits[]
```

What happened? Well, since you used `Set` (aka `=`), the evaluator evaluated the right hand side. It couldn't do anything with `IntegerDigits[x]`, so that remained as is. Then the `Select` went to work. `Select` can work with expressions other than `List`. For example, try this:

```
Select[test[1, 2, 3, 4], OddQ]
```

The result is

```
test[1, 3]
```

Now, `OddQ[x]` is `False`, the expression

```
Select[IntegerDigits[x], OddQ]
```

evaluates to

```
IntegerDigits[]
```

and since `IntegerDigits` doesn't expect an empty argument list, you get your message. This expression also just remains unevaluated, so that's the end of evaluating the right hand side. So now your definition for `f` is just

```
    f[x_] = IntegerDigits[]
```

which is not what we wanted. Going back to your original definition, you'll end up with the right hand side evaluating to

```
Total[IntegerDigits[]] - Total[IntegerDigits[]]
```

which eventually evaluates to `0`. So, your definition for `f` is just

```
f[x_] = 0
```

To keep the right hand side from evaluating immediately, use `SetDelayed` (aka `:=`):

```
f[x_] := Total@Select[IntegerDigits[x], OddQ] - Total@Select[IntegerDigits[x], EvenQ]
```

Comment: Your analysis also shows that the def. should be `f[x_Integer] :=...`, since `f[x]` or `f[y]` will give the same errors. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I agree, but finally decided I didn't want that distraction unless there were follow-ups.